# How do I use commands within tabular definition?

Tags: tables, macros, errors

Using commands within tabular definition result in error `! Missing $ inserted`. In this case, it is the `\,` that causes problems when calling the custom command. Same commands work fine outside tabular definition, so how do I use commands in the parameter?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\comtest}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{#1}}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}

\fbox{\comtest{Text\,}}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
I need to use the width measurement for the paragraph width within the tabular so I can specify to vertically center multiple cells. Below is a less-contrived example. Padding modifiers removed for brevity.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

%produces an image and following text vertically centered
% [image command, image width, text]
\newcommand{\vcenteredimagetext}[3]{{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}m{#2}@{}@{\ }>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\widthof{#3}}@{}}
#1&#3\\
\end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}

\vcenteredimagetext{\rule{0.5in}{0.5in}}{0.5in}{\bf{Text}}
\bf{Text}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT #2**:
Decided to go with `\raisebox` option [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129460/vertically-center-image-with-text-midpoint/129463) instead of pursuing fixes to this method further.

Comment: Can you give a more meaningful example? For this one, a `c` column would be sufficient.

Comment: note `\bf` has been deprecated sine latex2e was released, but if you do use it its syntax is `{\bf Text}` not `\bf{Text}` The whole construction is weird, if you want to vertically centre something, you could use a tabular, or more directly use `\raisebox{-.5\height}{Text}`

Comment: I just used the \bf as an example command. Feel free to modify it if you wish.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you would center an image that is a different height than the text? Ideally I'd like to center an image of any height at the center of the text height above the baseline, where the text may be anything. I'd need to intersperse several of these images within a single line of text, and still have the baselines of all the text line-up.

Comment: @TomH57 the `\raisebox` command I suggest above does that, there is no need for a table at all.

Comment: Looks like `\raisebox` might work after all if I can get a few things worked out. New question posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129460/vertically-center-image-with-text-midpoint).

Make a response recommending `\raisebox` and I'll mark it as the answer if I can get the lengths figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Interesting....

You don't really want to do that as it would calculate the width for every row of the table (your example only had one row but...) You can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\zz
\newcommand{\comtest}[1]{
\setlength{\zz}{\widthof{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{p{\zz}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}


\fbox{\comtest{Text\,}}

\end{document}
```

which avoids that, and works.

However arguably what you had should work, `\,` is declared as a robust command but it is being expanded at a place where `\protect` code is not being activated, so it takes the wrong (math mode) choice.

---

To make the original code work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\zzz#1{#1}
\def\@classz{\@classx
   \@tempcnta \count@
   \prepnext@tok
  \def\zzz##1{\unexpanded{\zzz}{\unexpanded{##1}}}%
   \@addtopreamble{\ifcase \@chnum
      \hfil
      \d@llarbegin
      \insert@column
      \d@llarend \hfil \or
      \hskip1sp\d@llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend \hfil \or
      \hfil\hskip1sp\d@llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend \or
   $\vcenter
   \@startpbox{\expandafter\zzz\expandafter{\@nextchar}}\insert@column \@endpbox $\or
   \vtop \@startpbox{\expandafter\zzz\expandafter{\@nextchar}}\insert@column \@endpbox \or
   \vbox \@startpbox{\expandafter\zzz\expandafter{\@nextchar}}\insert@column \@endpbox
  \fi}%
\prepnext@tok}

\makeatother


\newcommand{\comtest}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{#1}}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}

%\tracingall
\fbox{\comtest{Text\,}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from my first sample, other than you store the length in a temporary variable before using it. I need to know the width of text so that I can specify it when using a vertically centered m{}.

Comment: @TomH57 That is the only difference in the original answer.

Comment: @TomH57 It is a _very_ odd thing to do, to use a parbox that is the width of the text, are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken there's no other way to ensure the table is no wider than the content while still using vertical centering.

Comment: @TomH57 there are lots of ways, there is no point at all using a table just to get an mcolumn around a single cell. Especially `m` column with text isn't usually what you want as it destroys baseline alignment, to verntically centre an image you can use `\raisebox` or perhaps simpl the `adjustbox` package gives a nicer suntax.